# Call function in one controller to another controller

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel. I have some functions in `PaymentController`. I want to call those functions from `SmartpaySController`. Here is the function which is available in `PaymentController`. Help me to call that function by staying in `SmartpaySController`.

```
public function getPaymentFailed($paymentId) {

        $transactionData = $this->paymentRepo->find($paymentId);
        if($transactionData) {
            $data['quote'] = $this->quoteRepo->getQuoteById($transactionData->quote_id);
            $data['metaTitle'] = 'Payment failed';
            $data['returnMessage'] = $transactionData->return_message;
            return view('payment::payment.quote_payment_failed', $data);
        }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: If it's only the one method and it doesn't warrant creating a "Service" class then one possibility would be to create a trait that both your controllers use.

Answer (score 1):

```
Instead of calling controller methods, the better practice is that you can create traits like: app/Traits  and extend in controller
```

//trait

```
trait traitName {

    public function getData() {
        // .....
    }
}
```

//Controller

```
class ControlelrName extends Controller {
     use TraitName;
}
```

Comment: Totally agree that using controller method as business logic is an anti pattern in mvc :)

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to not call functions from one controller to another.
Make Helpers, Resources or implement same feature in other way

> Never use controllers as object

But if you want to do it anyway you can use:

**SomeController.php**

```
class SomeController extend Controller {
    public function someFunction(Request $request) {
        // Here Some Code
    }
}
```

**YourController.php**

```
use SomeController;
...
public function getPaymentFailed(Request $request, $paymentId) {
    $controller_data = (new SomeController)->someFunction($request);

    $transactionData = $this->paymentRepo->find($paymentId);
    if($transactionData) {
        $data['quote'] = $this->quoteRepo->getQuoteById($transactionData->quote_id);
        $data['metaTitle'] = 'Payment failed';
        $data['returnMessage'] = $transactionData->return_message;
        return view('payment::payment.quote_payment_failed', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
public function getPaymentFailed($paymentId)
```

to:

```
public static function getPaymentFailed($paymentId)
```

This will make it staticly available in your SmartpaySController by doing:

```
PaymentController::getPaymentFailed($paymentId);
```

Comment: Without changing **public function getPaymentFailed($paymentId)** as **public static function getPaymentFailed($paymentId)**, can't I call? Because this is a live project and already written functions. One more thing is that, if I change it as static, will it effect to others?

Comment: You have to make the function static or extend the PaymentController. Otherwise you cant call the function.

Comment: I think your website will still work when declaring your function static.
But i would still test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **[Real-Time Facades](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/facades#real-time-facades)**

> Using real-time facades, you may treat any class in your application
>   as if it were a facade.
>
> To generate a real-time facade, prefix the namespace of the imported
>   class with Facades:

```
//...

use use Facades\App\Http\Controllers\SomeController;

//...

return SomeController::getPaymentFailed($request, $paymentId);
```